# Pandas multiple boxplots - how to reduce spacing between plots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, boxplot, spacing

I have a plot with two boxplots:

[image]

There is an awful lot of spacing between lan_data and wan_data. I would like to reduce that spacing.

My dataframe is simply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lan_data':random.sample(range(1, 100), 100), 'wan_data':random.sample(range(1, 100), 100)})
```

I have looked and all answers I come across pertain to either reducing the axis width, which just squashes the plot, or changing the position of the plots - none of those solutions appear to be appropriate.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like:

`df.plot.box(box_padding = [top, bottom, left, right])`

or

`df.plot.box(subplot_spacing = 1.5)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try play with `widths`:

```
df.plot.box(widths=0.8)
```

[image]